# QT window not refreshing properly on MAC OS

Tags: macos, qt, qt5

I have built the VESC Tool for MAC OS from the linked git source https://github.com/vedderb/vesc_tool

But on building in MAC I am faced with the tool which is very sluggish in UI updates and is flickering a lot as shown by the below images..
[image: Bleeding UI]
[image: Non Rendered Icons]
[image: Missing Controls]

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PATH=/opt/Qt/5.9-static/bin:$PATH
rm -rf build/macos/*

# Original
qmake -config release "CONFIG += release_macos build_original"
make clean
make -j8 V=1
#rm -rf build/macos/obj
#cd build/macos
#zip vesc_tool_original_macos.zip `ls | grep -v '\.zip$'`
#ls | grep -v '\.zip$' | xargs rm -rf
#cd ../..
```

Comment: This is a bug report, not a StackOverflow question. Please notify the authors of the program about this issue and see if they can help you.

Comment: The build is proper adn responsive in Linux and Windows., and since the original authors provide no official support for mac-os it's a moot on that end.

Comment: Building the same using static QT works.

Comment: It sounds like it's not finding some platform plugins or can't load them because they can't load due to broken library dependencies?